# How to Parse a String with delimeters in Java

Tags: java, arrays

When I try to parse the following string I only Get The first array, I am not able to get the second and third part. This is a response I am receiving from an API and I cannot change it.

This is the string

```
[3451605#John#600#Doe],[3503101#Jane#100#Doe]
```

This is my code

```
 String String1= response.replace("[", "");
                        String String2= String1.replace("]", ""); 
                           String[] ss=String1.split("#");
                           for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++)
                             {
                               System.out.println(ss[i]);
                               resp1= ss[0];                                
                               resp2= ss[1];
                               resp3= ss[2];
                               resp4= ss[3];                


                             }
```

This is the response I get when I print out the response.

```
3451605
John
600
Doe,3503101
Jane
100
Doe
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the output you want?

Comment: First do a split on comma, then go inside the array do a split on Hash#..

Comment: Have you thought about regex?

Comment: what you expect to have? what is the general problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to de-serialize the response by splitting as follows:

- Firstly by `,` to delimit your objects
- Then clean up the `[]` and split by `#`

**Example**

```
// test response
String response = "[3451605#John#600#Doe],[3503101#Jane#100#Doe]";
// itemizing "objects"
String[] items = response.split(",");
// iterating "objects"
for (String item: items) {
    // cleaning square brackets and splitting by "#"
    String[] properties = item.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").split("#");
    // printing each object's properties
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(properties));
}
```

**Output**

```
[3451605, John, 600, Doe]
[3503101, Jane, 100, Doe]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are splitting string1 not string2

```
       String String1= response.replace("[", "");
     String String2= String1.replace("]", ""); 
        String[] ss=String2.split("#");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess yu want an Output like this:

```
3451605
John
600
Doe
3503101
Jane
100
Doe
```

So you have to split on `#` and  `,`.

```
       String[] ss=String2.split("[#,]");
```